# Security Scanner Report in Owasp zap

Tags: security, security-review, security-scanner, zap-scanner

How to scan my salesforce app in Owasap zap, need to cover everything such as custom objects, flow, process builder, reports and dashboard, etc. at the end need to generate a report, is possible?

[image]

Comment: do not down vote, this is a completely valid question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the [ISVforce Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/security_review_partner_security_portal_scanners.htm) documentation on Security Review and scanners carefully.

If you are building a Salesforce managed package, you should be submitting a Checkmarx report, not an OWASP ZAP report. Your report will primarily focus on Apex code - note the reference in the tooltip to *scannable code*. You can gain access to Checkmarx through the Partner Security Portal as discussed in the documentation linked above.

Comment: Hi David,  but in that picture they mentioned owasp zap also can scanner report, because Owasp zap is open source, that's why am asking. sure it is not possible?

Comment: OWASP ZAP is a web application scanner. It isn't for scanning managed package code.

Comment: There is any other open-source available like  Checkmarx

Comment: Hi David, small doubt https://security.secure.force.com/security/tools/forcecom/scanner  in Force.com Scanner can also scan the organization, what is different in it..between Force.com Scanner and Checkmarx

Comment: That _is_ a Checkmarx portal. Please read the instructions in the ISVforce Guide, which is the official documentation.

Comment: Hi, we are using the webapi (soap) as a backend in our salesforce app.do i need to attach the ZAP report with it ? please suggest

Comment: @UsmanYounas Please check out [ask] and [help/on-topic] and open a new post if appropriate. Comments are not for follow-up with new topics.